# Problem with Check for updates in RAD studio

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I installed Embarcadero RAD Studio (Delphi 2009).  When the IDE ran for the first time, it downloaded updates and ran the MSI automatically. Accidentally I pressed cancel, instead of ok.

So I thought of reopening the studio so that it may check for updates.  But this time it didnot happen !!

So, I used "Check for updates" from menu options.  Surprising it gave me "RAD sudio is upto date".

What is the location of these downloaded update files on the system? Where do these files get saved after auto download?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following location 
<\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data{65B1AA84-C1DF-4A2E-A28C-E242BD7DE4B3}>

there is a file **InstalledUpdates.dat** , open the file in notepad, and you can see the entries of updates installed.

Remove the entries from the file and save it.

Now click on "Check for updates".  It brings up the screen giving available updates and then you can proceed further.

Note that updates screen asks to download again, but it doesnt download, as updates are already downloaded and on clicking next it proceeds to screen where it asks for install updates.

Thanks & Regards,
Pavan.

Comment: The GUID was different on my system, but the advice worked for me. I had to rename the file and create a new one because it was in use. In my case the original update failed because it wasn't running as an Administrator when it launched.

Answer (score 5):

Registered users can download the updates here:

http://cc.embarcadero.com/reg/delphi

You can also get a number of "freebies" there including the TMS Smooth Controls, the InfoPower Essentials, and Marco Cantus "Delphi 2009 Handbook" as a PDF.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem also, you don't have to reinstall Delphi!

I can't remember the exact location, but you have to find were the update started downloading the update (I don't remember if it is on the Documents folder or the user folder) and execute the update manually.

Try searching for BDS, Codegear or RadStudio under you User's folder, I'm sure you will find the temp location, from there you can just execute the update and it will resume.

Answer (score 1):

Another tip about Delphi updating that confused me for a while: When installing help update 2, I got kind of a popup under. Some question was asked (by the separate installer), but it wasn't modal, and switching to and from the IDE didn't bring it up.